# How to distribute peoples on calendar dates in an harmonic way in Python?

Tags: python, csv, calendar, scheduled-tasks, distribution

How to distribute peoples on calendar dates in an harmonic way in Python?

I need the options to obligate some people in certain dates. Exclude the possibility of some people in certain dates.

I also need a possibility of have more than a single person per date. I already have a ".csv" file with some obligations and exclusions per person

(non native English speaker)

I already have the names like: John, Peter, Anna, Elizabeth...
The days, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15... John must be in the day 4, and Anna can't be in the day 11, so

1 - [...]

2 - [...]

3 - [...]

4 - John

5 - [...]

6 - [...]

7 - [...]

8 - [...]

9 - [...]

10 - [...]

11 - [...] not(Anna)

12 - [...]

13 - [...]

14 - [...]

15 - [...]

Now I need to distribute the others name in a democratic way... its a work schedule and its important that the names dont be too concentrated.

The weekends and holiday must be proportional too

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for this problem, and what a sample solution should look like?

Comment: I already have the names like: John, Peter, Anna, Elizabeth...
The days, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15...

John must be in the day 4, and Anna can't be in the day 11, so

1  - [...]
2  - [...]
3  - [...]
4  - John
5  - [...]
6  - [...]
7  - [...]
8  - [...]
9  - [...]
10 - [...]
11 - [...] not(Anna)
12 - [...]
13 - [...]
14 - [...]
15 - [...]

Now I need to distribute the others name in a democratic way... its a work schedule and its important that the names dont be too concentrated.

Comment: (You can use the [edit] button to add your example into your question to make it easier to understand)

Comment: A simple approach would be to randomly allocate (within the rules). Then write a function to rate how good the allocation is. Repeat, keeping each better allocation.